# Issues with angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker.js datetimepicker

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have just started off with BootStrap, however stranded with  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function error message. Could someone let me know what went missing with this code?

Comment: Problems solved by updating the javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating JavaScript, this may solve your problem.